# Changing shortcode align in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have next problem. When I change shortcode position in TinyMCE editor it doesn't change on page.
Here is string from TinyMCE:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">[title size="1"]Title[/title]</p>
```

And here is part of page's source:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"></p>
<h1>Title</h1>
```

As You can see, for not understandable for me reason title is not betwen p tags,
What can be the reason for that ?

Comment: The reasone was in H* tag. It not valid to store it inside p tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H1 can't be inside p. Because h1 and p are block elements. Use span instead p

```
<span style="text-align: center;">[title size="1"]Title[/title]</span>
```